# Trying to create a drop down filter for displaying tableau data over varying date ranges

Tags: filter, parameters, calculated-field, tableau-desktop

I have parameters set in a drop down, and based on those dropdowns, I'd like a filter to change the displayed data corresponding to All or the last 3,6, or 9 months.  When I use the following calc'ed field as a filter, it displays all values for 'Max" as desired, but displays nothing for any of the other options.  What am I doing wrong here?

```
IF [date_filter_options] = 'Max' THEN
    ATTR([COLL].[_Id])
ELSEIF [date_filter_options] = '3 Months' THEN
    (IF DATEDIFF('month', ATTR([COLL].[Date]), NOW()) <= 3
    THEN ATTR([COLL].[_Id])
    END)
ELSEIF [date_filter_options] = '6 Months' THEN
    (IF DATEDIFF('month', ATTR([COLL].[Date]), NOW()) <= 6
    THEN ATTR([COLL].[_Id])
    END)
ELSEIF [date_filter_options] = '9 Months' THEN
    (IF DATEDIFF('month', ATTR([COLL].[Date]), NOW()) <= 9
    THEN ATTR([COLL].[_Id])
    END)
END
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go a different path.

Your parameter is set up okay but I would create a new Calc Field with cases (Lets call it "Calc"):

[image: Calc field using parameter]

After that I would create 4 new Calc fields, Max, 3 Months, 6 Months and 9 Months. Each one of those would compare dates and return what you need:

[image]

Then I would display Calc and also put Calc as true into your filters:

[image]

Set it to True and then change your parameter.

Lets test it out. I've filtered myself to 2022 and I'm displaying all months to give you an idea how it could work.

Parameter set to 3:

[image]

Parameter set to max:

[image]